# Dexie toArray() Promise

Tags: promise, dexie

I need to create and consume an array from Dexie ordeBy Promise

```
var list = [];
const ms = wmsLocalDb.table1.orderBy("index").toArray();
ms.each(m => list.push(m)).then(
   //When list is complete I want to consume 
   for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { 
       //something
   }
);
```

But i cannot read list array.
Best regards
Ingd

Comment: Array doesn't have an `.each()` method. Besides, everything looks to be synchronous, so you don't need promise(s), and without promise(s), you don't need `.then()`.

Comment: In Dexie.js the Return Value of toArray() is a Promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something along the following lines :

```
wmsLocalDb.table1.orderBy("index").toArray()
.then(list => {
    list.forEach(item => {
       //something
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    // handle error
});
```